# Log4net file name with date

Tags: asp.net, wpf, windows-services, log4net

I'm using a log4net.
It creates a log file named: log.3.txt etc.,
and when file size reaches 10 MB a new file is created.

The App.Config looks like the following:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileSizeAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="Logs/log.txt" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />      
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
      <countDirection value="1" />
      <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[%date{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}][%level%][%message]%newline"></conversionPattern>
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileSizeAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

I need:

1) the file name to be written in this format: log_2014052**0**-150010.txt
//(yyyyMMdd-HHmmss)
Here number replaced with date.

2) and when the application is reopened it need to continue to write to the previous file, till it size reaches 10 MB, and only after it need to create a new file with new date: log_2014052**1**-150010.txt

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You're not going to be able to do that out-of-the box: adding the date to the log file name and is only possible if you use a `<datePattern>` and `rollingStyle = Composite` but if you include the seconds in that you're going to roll your logs every second! If you're prepared to do a bit of hacking on the [source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/log4net/Appender/RollingFileAppender.cs?view=markup&sortdir=down) and use a custom build then it would be possible, though perhaps not trivial..

Comment: Thank you. Can I write date in file name when it reaches 10 Mb without custom changes on log4net?

Comment: @grscripto Writing the date in the file name is possible when rolling files by date or date and size, but the file will roll when the date changes as well as when it reaches 10MB.